# Evaluating the value of CD

Tags: geometry

[image]

Any tips or solution will be welcomed. Do I need to find sector area  to evaluate the length of CD?

Comment: evaluate the angles first

Comment: CD and AB are parallel: use @eccstartup hint, then

Comment: Okay, then will I evaluate the area of CAB and DCA?

Comment: I think the angle of OAC is useful.

Comment: then what about their angle?

Comment: You could use [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Inscribed_Angle_Theorem) to to find $\angle COB$ and $\angle DOA$ first (as was done in the answer below, I presume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\because\overline{AB}\parallel\overline{CD}\\
\therefore\angle{ACD}=\angle{CAB}=45^\circ\\
\therefore\widehat{AD}=\widehat{BC}=90^\circ\\
\because\widehat{AB}+\widehat{CD}+\widehat{AD}+\widehat{BC}=360^\circ\\
\therefore\widehat{AB}+\widehat{CD}=360^\circ-(\widehat{AD}+\widehat{BC})=180^\circ\\
\because\widehat{AB}=2\widehat{CD}\\
\therefore\widehat{CD}=180^\circ\div3=60^\circ\\
\therefore\widehat{CD}=\frac{60^\circ}{360^\circ}\times2\pi\times8=\frac{8\pi}{3}
$$

Comment: $\widehat{CD}$ denotes?

Comment: @ComplexGuy Sometimes angle of minor arc $CD$, sometimes length of minor arc $CD$. Decided by context. When I wrote $\widehat{CD}=60^\circ$ it means angle. When I wrote $\widehat{CD}=\frac{8\pi}{3}$ it means length.

Comment: $\therefore\widehat{AD}=\widehat{BC}=90^\circ\\  $ 

Why it is $90^0$. is that the sector area?

Comment: If $\widehat{CAB}$ is $45^\circ$, then $\widehat{COB}$ is $90^\circ$.